# DELETE ROWS FROM PANDAS DATASET

Tags: python, regex, pandas

Below is my Dataset, I want to delete all tweets that containing word "pol" (first 3 letters for polsek,polda,polres,etc) in at_word column, how can I do that?

[mydataset](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xxw0M.png)

Answer (score 0):

```
df = df[df.tweet.str.contains('pol')==False]
print(df)
```

For more details, please refer to [this](http://https:/https://www.statology.org/pandas-drop-rows-that-contain-string/).

Answer (score 0):

Create a boolean mask which is True for all cases where `df["at_word"]` first 3 letters equal to "pol"

Then you can do

`mask = df["at_word"].apply(lambda x : True if x[:3].lower()=="pol" else false)`

`df[~mask]`